# Use Interface to resolve MediatR IRequestHandler instead of the class

Tags: c#, cqrs, .net-5, mediatr

I have implement MediatR in .net 5 application and want to resolve require dependencies using Handler interfaces. Currently I using class name to resolve as following

```
_mediator.Send(new GetDeviceByIMEI(imei)); // want to use interface ??

 //var result = await _mediator.Send(IGetHandHeldByIMEI????);
```

full code reference as following;

### Handler Interface

```
 public interface IGetDeviceByIMEIEventHandler
{
    Task<DeviceWrapperDataView> Handle(GetDeviceByIMEI request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

### Query Interface

```
public interface IGetDeviceByIMEI
{
    string IMEI { get; set; }
}
```

### Query

```
 public class GetDeviceByIMEI: IRequest<DeviceWrapperDataView>
{

    public string IMEI { get; set; }

    public GetDeviceByIMEI(string imei)
    {
        this.IMEI = imei;
    }
}
```

### Handler

```
public class GetDeviceByIMEIEventHandler : IRequestHandler<GetDeviceByIMEI, DeviceWrapperDataView>, IGetDeviceByIMEIEventHandler
{      
    private readonly IDeviceEntity _DeviceEntity;
  
    public GetDeviceByIMEIEventHandler(IDeviceEntity DeviceEntity)
    {
        _DeviceEntity = DeviceEntity;
    }


    public async Task<DeviceWrapperDataView> Handle(GetDeviceByIMEI request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // code to get data 
        return DeviceOutput;
    }
}
```

### API controller

```
private readonly IMediator _mediator;

  public DeviceController(
        IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

 [HttpGet()]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetDeviceByIMEI(string imei)
 {
   Var result = await _mediator.Send(new GetDeviceByIMEI(imei));
   // want to use 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that you have to register your handler in the container with each of the class that inherit your query interface.

For instance with the code you provided.

```
public interface IGetDeviceByIMEI : IRequest<DeviceWrapperDataView>
{
    string IMEI { get; set; }
}


public class GetDeviceByIMEI: IGetDeviceByIMEI 
{

    public string IMEI { get; set; }

    public GetDeviceByIMEI(string imei)
    {
        this.IMEI = imei;
    }
}

public class AnotherGetDeviceByIMEI: IGetDeviceByIMEI 
{
    
    public string IMEI { get; set; }
    
    public GetDeviceByIMEI(string imei)
    {
        this.IMEI = imei;
    }
}

public class GetDeviceByIMEIEventHandler : IRequestHandler<IGetDeviceByIMEI, DeviceWrapperDataView>, IGetDeviceByIMEIEventHandler
{      
    private readonly IDeviceEntity _DeviceEntity;
  
    public GetDeviceByIMEIEventHandler(IDeviceEntity DeviceEntity)
    {
        _DeviceEntity = DeviceEntity;
    }


    public async Task<DeviceWrapperDataView> Handle(IGetDeviceByIMEI request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // code to get data 
        return DeviceOutput;
    }
}
```

Once you have done that, you have to register the handler in your container with each use case.

For instance in .Net Core, you can do it with the serviceCollection in the StartUp class.

```
serviceCollection.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<GetDeviceByIMEI, DeviceWrapperDataView>, GetDeviceByIMEIEventHandler >();
serviceCollection.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<AnotherGetDeviceByIMEI, DeviceWrapperDataView>, GetDeviceByIMEIEventHandler >();
```

Regards.